# (В) каждую субботу

Tags: предлоги

Оба ли варианта (с предлогом и без) являются допустимыми?

"В каждую субботу" и "каждую субботу"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта допустимы, но имеют разные семантические оттенки. Беспредложное управление В.п. возможно **при неопределенном указании на время** (каждый момент/каждый день), а при наличии предлога В  имеется в виду каждый момент/каждый день **из  некоторого промежутка времени**, например:

***Каждую субботу*** мы ходим в театр или в музей.
За месяц до Рождества **в каждую субботу** здесь устраивают благотворительные ярмарки.

Надо сказать, что форма ***каждую субботу*** в обычной речи используется значительно чаще (по частотности  этот вариант практически вытесняет предложную форму), но в научной литературе, где важна точность,  предложное управление применяется, например: *В другом случае они колеблются так, что **в каждый момент** они отклонены на одинаковый угол в противоположные стороны.*

Примеры:

Он стал бледный и тощий. **Каждую субботу** уезжает в Таллинн.  [Василий Аксенов. Звездный билет // «Юность», 1961]

...на пианино и на подзеркальнике цвели в гранёных вазах нарядные цветы, ― по моему приказу ей доставляли **каждую субботу** свежие...[И. А. Бунин. Чистый понедельник (1944)]

За четыре недели до Рождества католички и протестантки немного зашевелились. По их обычаю, **в каждую субботу,** четыре раза перед Рождеством, по вечерам они собирались по комнатам ...и рассказывали старинные германские христианские легенды.  [А. И. Делианич. Вольфсберг-373 (1945-1960)]

Answer (score 1):

Это явно неравноценные варианты. Вариант с предлогом практически *не* употребляется (хотя есть даже книга с таким названием), для него непросто придумать подходящий контекст - как и для выражения "в каждый день". Пример такого полуфантастического контекста:

> Всю эту зиму по субботам он занимался резьбой по дереву. В каждую субботу
>   успевал вырезать на продажу по четыре фигурки Буратино.